# InAppWebView in Flutter not working with controller

Tags: flutter, flutter-inappwebview

I am trying to connect to my payment gateway using InAppWebView using controller. It is working correctly except I don't want the back button to work unless it is a redirect_url or a cancel_url.

```
    WebViewController()
      ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
      ..setNavigationDelegate(
        NavigationDelegate(
          onNavigationRequest: (navigation) {
            if (navigation.url == PaymentConstants.REDIRECT_URL) {
              return NavigationDecision.navigate;
            }
            if (navigation.url == PaymentConstants.CANCEL_URL) {
              return NavigationDecision.navigate;
            }
            return NavigationDecision.prevent;
          },
        ),
      )
      ..loadRequest(Uri.parse(paymentUrl));
```